# Build a WebExtension with Angular and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firefox-addon-webextensions

I try to realize a WebExtension from an application Angular and Ionic.
The application loads in the extension and I can send messages between the Content Script and the Background Script, however, the TypeScript code is not interpreted and I can not store the data in the variables of the application. I would like to retrieve the contents of the web page in my Angular application.
Can you help me please ? Do you know if it's technically possible? I thank you for your response.

**manifest.json :**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  //[...]
  "background": {
    "page": "index.html#/background"
  },
  "content_scripts":
  [{
    "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content_script.js"]
  }]
}
```

**content_script.js :**

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage({url: location.href});
```

**Background Script (Angular) :**

```
ngOnInit() {
    var browser = browser || chrome;
    browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(this.showMessage);
}

public url: string;
showMessage(message) {
    alert(message.url); // It works
    this.url = message.url;
    alert(this.url); // Doesn't work
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: No, I don't have error. My application is not interpreted as an AngularJS application because I can not call the services of the application.
In the example, message.url retrieves the information well, but as soon as I want to store it in another variable, it does not work: this.url = message.url;

With the following configuration (manifest.json), my AngularJS application appears very well in the popup of the extension, but what I'm trying to do is run this application in background, to be able to reuse the data in the popup.

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }

Comment: Sorry, I have this error : "Error: this is undefined"

Comment: where at? please add the error and a stacktrace to the question itselft, it might be helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved !

I can not give an explanation, but this line:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(this.showMessage);
```

Is the same as this code:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    alert(message.url); // It works
    this.url = message.url;
    alert(this.url); // Doesn't work
});
```

The "functions" are interpreted differently by TypeScript, so you had to call the method in this way:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  this.url = message.url;
  alert(this.url); // It works
});
```

If this can be used, here is the code that allows to realize the route "background" with the framework Ionic:

```
const links: any = [
  { component: Page, name: 'Background', segment: 'background' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {links})
  ],
  bootstrap: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: []
})
```

TypeScript type definitions for WebExtensions : https://github.com/michael-zapata/web-ext-types